# If VB condition with or

Tags: php, if-statement, vbulletin

I got an if like:

```
<vb:if condition="$channel['nodeid'] != 16">
        <tr><td>Something</td></tr>
</vb:if>
```

but i need it to also check for 20 so it must be something like:

```
if != 16 || 20
```

how do i write that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

```
<vb:if condition="!in_array($channel['nodeid'], array(16,20))">
        <tr><td>Something</td></tr>
</vb:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
<vb:if condition="$channel['nodeid'] != 16 || $channel['nodeid'] != 20">
        <tr><td>Something</td></tr>
</vb:if>
```

Comment: it should... You can also try replacing `||` with simply `or` ... that should work too, I think

Comment: I agree it should... but it wont :( Also replaced || with or but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how vbulletin works, but i guess you need something like this:

```
if $channel['nodeid'] != 16 || $channel['nodeid'] != 20
```